# Thanos with remote read and write

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-operator

I want to add a third party prometheus node to our thanos setup, they donot want to open up ports so I was going through some links about remote read and write, how can we incorporate them in our simple thanos/prometheus setup?
Thanks:grinning:

Answer (score 1):

Thanos has a [receiver component](https://thanos.io/tip/components/receive.md/), which allows remote write on Thanos.
by configuring `remote_write` field in the Prometheus config file with the address of receiver, Prometheus will upload metrics to receiver in real-time.
then you can query by querier on receiver and store gateway.